# Product filtering problems with Laravel Query Builder

Tags: ajax, laravel

I try to implement ajax based filtering in my ecommerce project homepage for searching a product. I am using Laravel Query Builder. My Query for filtering products is given below-

```
 $result= DB::table('products')
    ->leftjoin('products_description','products.products_id','products_description.products_id')
    ->leftjoin('image_categories', 'products.products_image', '=', 'image_categories.image_id')
    ->leftjoin('products_to_categories','products.products_id','products_to_categories.products_id')
    ->leftjoin('categories','products_to_categories.categories_id','categories.categories_id')
    ->when($category_slug, function($q) use ($category_slug) {
        return $q->where('categories.categories_slug', $category_slug);
    })
    ->where('products_name','like',"%{$querval}%")
    ->where('image_categories.image_type','=','ACTUAL')
    ->orderby('products.products_id','DESC')
    ->take(5)
    ->get();
```

I get every product  twice in search result. don't know why. A sample response is given in this picture.
[image: response]

Can anyone help me to optimize my query for getting the desired result?

Comment: what is the columns you want to select?

Comment: how many images you are getting for each product, i think that is creating problem for multiple records.

Comment: i want to selects products_name , id and image_path column

Comment: i am getting one image for each product. but one product comes twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

join with categories table only when you have to.

and select your columns strictly. then group by selected columns.

```
 $result= DB::table('products')
            ->leftjoin('products_description','products.products_id','products_description.products_id')
            ->leftjoin('image_categories', 'products.products_image', '=', 'image_categories.image_id')
            ->when($category_slug, function($q) use ($category_slug) {
                return $q->leftjoin('products_to_categories','products.products_id','products_to_categories.products_id')
                    ->leftjoin('categories','products_to_categories.categories_id','categories.categories_id')
                    ->where('categories.categories_slug', $category_slug);
            })
            ->where('products_name','like',"%{$querval}%")
            ->where('image_categories.image_type','=','ACTUAL')
            ->orderby('products.products_id','DESC')
            ->select(['products_name','products.id','image_path'])
            ->groupBy(['products_name','products.id','image_path'])
            ->take(5)
            ->get();
```

Comment: No Brother. products_name comes from  products_description table.

Comment: well done, I have updated my answer based on that

Comment: Thanks Brother. I understand my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

you can use from `groupBy` to avoid comming repeated data.
try this one:

```
 $result= DB::table('products')
->leftjoin('products_description','products.products_id','products_description.products_id')
->leftjoin('image_categories', 'products.products_image', '=', 'image_categories.image_id')

->when($category_slug, function($q) use ($category_slug) {
    return $q->where('categories.categories_slug', $category_slug);
})
->where('products_name','like',"%{$querval}%")
->where('image_categories.image_type','=','ACTUAL')
->orderby('products.products_id','DESC')
->groupBy('products_name','products.products_id')
->take(5)
->get();
```